# How to lock an existing key?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am writing some c# code to write to a redis server. The code is multithreading so whenever I want to make changes to a certain key:value pair, I need to lock the "key"

I am using the StackExchange.Redis library. In this library, an interface IDatabase stands for the redis db and provides methods to read from/write to redis. It has 2 lock-related methods: bool LockTake(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, TimeSpan expiry, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None); & bool LockRelease(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);

However, the LockTake() can only lock non-existing keys, according to this post: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/144

But I want to lock a key even if it has been created since multiple threads may try to update it concurrently. How can I do that in c#?

Comment: Place your changes inside a lock(object) {} block.  Keep in mind that the reason that the Redis library's LockTake command only works on non-existing keys is that it avoids having a race condition where thread A is trying to set a value for key "Z" to 1 and thread B is trying to set the value for key "Z" to 2. If that was to occur and it seems like that is what you are coding for, you are going to have to figure out which thread should "win".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a key-based locking library, such as the one I made called `AsyncKeyedLock`. It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarkCiliaVincenti/AsyncKeyedLock) and packaged over at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncKeyedLock).

Usage example:

```
var locker = new AsyncKeyedLocker<string>(o =>
{
   o.PoolSize = 20;
   o.PoolInitialFill = 1;
});

// asynchronous code
using (await locker.LockAsync(key, cancellationToken))
{
   ...
}

// synchronous code
using (locker.Lock(key))
{
   ...
}
```